# Tablet Layout, change depending on screen orientation Error

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, fragment

Basically my question is kinda "easy": 
**I have this tablet layout in landscape:**

[image: Tablet Layout Landscape]

**and want to change the layout if the user rotate the tablet into portrait mode, to this layout:**

[image: Tablet Layout Portrait]

In the first, landscape, layout the Ui show two fragments at once, `Fragment1` on the left and `Fragment2` on the right. The container of `Fragment2` is a `ViewPager`, which also contain `Fragment3`. `Fragment3` is visible of the user swipe to it, or clicks the tab in the `ActionBar`.

In the second, portrait, layout the Ui show all three `Fragment`s at once, the `ViewPager` is removed, the tabs, too, because they are needless.

I creat the landscape layout in my MainActivity like this:

```
    // ActionBar Stuff
    mActionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    mActionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

    // Swipe Stuff
    mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(fm);
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

    // Initialize Tabs
    Tab1 = mActionbar.newTab().setText("Tab1");
    Tab2 = mActionbar.newTab().setText("Tab2");

    // Set Tab to Fragment // they're initialized here and accessed in the ViewPager (mPager)
    Fragment1 = new FirstFragment();
    Fragment3 = new ThirdFragment();

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_one_container, Fragment1).commit();

    // //TabListener///////////////////////////
    Tab1.setTabListener(new TabsListener(mApp, 0 + "", mPager));
    Tab2.setTabListener(new TabsListener(mApp, 1 + "", mPager));

    // //Add Tabs//////////////////////////////
    mActionbar.addTab(Tab1);
    mActionbar.addTab(Tab2);
```

The `ViewPager` switch between these two Fragments at swipe and to some more complicated things, like replacing `Fragment2` with other `Fragment`s at runtime (for navigation).

So far everything is fine, my code for the portrait layout is similar:

```
    // ActionBar Stuff
    mActionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

    // Swipe Stuff
    mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(fm);
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

    // Set Tab to Fragment // they're initialized here and accessed in the ViewPager (mPager)
    Fragment1 = new FirstFragment();
    Fragment3 = new ThirdFragment();

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_one_container, Fragment1);
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_three_container, Fragment3);
    ft.commit();
```

The ViewPager is the container of `Fragment2`, the other containers are explained in the code above.

The Layout Files `R.layout.main_tablet_land` and `R.layout.main_tablet_port` are in `layout-lard-land` and `layout-large-port`.

My actual problem is not the displaying, this works, my problem is the orientation change, I get this Exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment Fragment3`

I overrode `onConfiguratioChange` and tried to reapply the layout with `setContentView(layout)` and call the method for the layout `tablet_land` (the first block of code) and `tablet_port` (the second block). (and many more ..)

Any ideas how to avoid this?

Edit: No ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add some code to clear out fragment3 if there no container for it in two panel layout:

So, try to rewrite your XXX_FragmentActivity onCreate method like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
    // fragment 3 trick
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment oldFragment3 = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_three_container);
    View fragment3Container = findViewById(R.id.fragment_three_container);
    if(null==fragment3Container && null!=oldFragment3){
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(oldFragment3);
        ft.commit();
        fm.executePendingTransactions();
    }
    // other stuff
}
```